# How to choice route by expression value in Mule ESB

Tags: esb

I am new to the development of MULE.I want to choice route a method which is having 3 paremeters(integer,date,date).How to give expression in this case.

This is what I have done till now.

```
<component class="Sample" />
        <choice>
            <when expression="????????????"evaluator="groovy">
                <vm:outbound-endpoint path="internal queue" exchange-pattern="request-response"/>
            </when>
            <when expression="payload instanceof java.lang.Exception" evaluator="groovy">
                <vm:outbound-endpoint path="userErrorHandler" exchange-pattern="request-response"/>
            </when>
        </choice>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you could do  expression="payload.field == somevalue" in the when expression.

Also the choice won't work without `<otherwise>` i know!!!

so use as below

```
<choice>
   <when expression="payload.field == somevalue" evaluator="groovy">
     <vm:outbound-endpoint path="internal queue" exchange-pattern="request-response"/>
   </when>
   <otherwise>
   </otherwise>
</choice>
```

Or you could use

```
<message-filter>
```

Comment: According to the v3.3 [documentation](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Routing+Message+Processors#RoutingMessageProcessors-Choice), you can leave the otherwise tag off (will throw an exception if none of the choices match) -- not sure if this was ever different